# Form field with underscore doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm using a form to obtain the data from a post request and I noticed some behavior I'm not familiar with.  I have two versions of my form shown below.  The only variation is that in the second version of the form, I have an underscore in my variable names.

```
class EditTitleForm(Form):
    newTitle = StringField('newTitle')
    currentTitle = StringField('currentTitle')

class EditTitleForm(Form):
    new_title = StringField('newTitle')
    current_title = StringField('currentTitle')
```

However, when I try `print(form.new_title.data)` and `print(form.current_title.data)` I get an empty line, but when I switch the form to the version without the underscores, everything prints out fine.  Why is that?

```
@auth.route('/edit_title', methods=['POST'])
def edit_title():
    data = MultiDict(mapping=request.json)
    print(data)
    form = EditTitleForm(data)
    print(form.newTitle.data)
    print(form.currentTitle.data)
```

Comment: Is this WTForms, or something else? If it is WTForms the underscore form should work (see e.g. http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#defining-forms) and you should raise a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The names of the fields correspond to the keys in the data being read.  If you change the field names, you need to change the keys in the JSON data as well.  Setting the label (the first argument to a field) doesn't effect this, that's only used when rendering the fields as HTML.

```
# if attribute name is new_title
new_title = StringField()

# then data key must be new_title as well
data = {
    "new_title": "Stack Overflow"
}
```

WTForms *can* work with JSON, but if you want something more suited to that, try [Marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/) or another serialization library.